# VBA Delete all the text in ActiveDocument Word VBA script

Tags: vba, ms-word

My ActiveDocument only contains TEXT.

I want to delete all the text in the active Document and set it to the text stored in a string.

E.g.

```
Dim str as String
str = "bla bla bla  .  .  ."
ActiveDocument.Selection.
     .Find = ?? ' I dont know what to find becuase I just want to delete all the texts.
     .Replace.Text = str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply overwrite the full text, I think this should work:

```
Dim str As String
str = "bla bla bla ..."

ActiveDocument.Range.Text = str
```